# Convert lat,lng into Address and show on infoWindow google map api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have list of lat, lng values in object

```
var path = [{"lat":"12.9247903824","lng":"77.5806503296"},{"lat":"10.9974470139","lng":"76.9459457397"}]
```

Here i have to convert latlng into address and have to show marker and infowindow. Address have to be shown in info window

I have tried this one, i have getting address and multiple markers but i not able to show address on info windows.. last infowindow only showing address

```js
for (var i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(path[i]["lat"], path[i]["lng"]);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: pos,
        map: map
    });

    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': pos}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            infowindow.setContent(results[i].formatted_address);
        } else {
            alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You're looping over your array of coordinates, getting the address for each, then updating the content of a single infowindow.  When the loop finishes, the content of that infowindow will be the address for the last of those coordinates.  Add the code to your question where you create the infowindow, in order to get a useful answer.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a listener to open the infowindow when you click a marker? Insert the geocoder function inside that listener, do the geocode, set content to the infowindow and then open the infowindow.