# How to get latlng on click on marker and address have to be shown in infoWindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have several Markers in my google map apis

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: pos,
                    map: map
                });
                var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();   
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                    return function() {
                        infoWindow.setContent(setInfoWindow({this.position}));
                        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                    }
                })(marker, i));
```

Here, When i clicking on marker, i have showing infowindow and same time, i have assigning the address on infowindow which is converted from latlng to address

this is setInfoWindow();

```
function setInfoWindow(pos){
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': pos}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            console.log(results.formatted_address);
                return results.formatted_address;
        } else {
          alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
        }
    });
}
```

Here, It is showing undefined.

Am i correct on this procedure?

My simple idea is

When i click on marker, i have to be get latlng from marker and converted into address and have to be shown into infowindow

Comment: which line / variable is 'undefined'?

Comment: Duplicate of [Convert lat,lng into Address and show on infoWindow google map api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31201337/convert-lat-lng-into-address-and-show-on-infowindow-google-map-api)

Answer (score 2):

Where you call setInfoWindow you're passing in a structure with the `{ }` notation around the position:

```
setInfoWindow({this.position})
```

However in the function itself, you're treating it as if it's a single simple variable when you refer to it directly like:

```
function setInfoWindow(pos){
```

and then

```
 geocoder.geocode({'latLng': pos}
```

Just pass in the position itself to the function:

```
setInfoWindow(this.position)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is issued because of async. method.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                    return function() {
                        setInfoWindow(this.position);
                        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                    }
                })(marker, i));


function setInfoWindow(pos){
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': pos}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                infoWindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
        } else {
          alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
        }
    });
}
```

When i click on marker, i have calling one method, in that, i showing infowindow